# Python and Skype: `skype --callto` in subprocess finishes early

Tags: python, scripting, skype

Python documentation on `subprocess.check_call` [says](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) that it will wait for the command to complete. However, if you fire up skype and then run the code snippet provided below, you will see that the line "Finished calling" appears almost instantly (even before skype finishes dialing support). The call still takes place even though the script finishes execution. Could you please explain why?

```py
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['skype', '--callto', "echo123"])
print("Finished calling!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like skype uses the client-server model: there is a running process `skype` and when one invokes `skype --callto echo123`, then it looks for that running process, tells it to make the call and immediately exits. The first process then takes the liberty of actually making the call.